# Перемена PictureBox

Tags: c#

Как заполнить значение PictureBox для того, чтобы потом можно было их менять местами?

Comment: "значение" picturebox`а легко перерисовывается, поэтому опишите проблему подробнее

Answer (score 2):

**Изучайте английский, там все понятно.** Для установки изображения нужно посмотреть на свойства, там все есть. `Image, Picture, ImageSource` или другие свойства. Но для этого нужно иметь объект изображения. Bitmap или Image. Они легко загружаются через т.н. конструктор через `new Bitmap("FileName.jpg");` Сначала рекомендую открыть в проекте элемент References, там двойным кликом выбрать `System.Drawing` и изучить все то, что покажется полезным.